# Why say "Tennyson has looked to..." instead of "Tennyson looked to..."?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect

> Tennyson **has** looked to Shakespeare for inspiration. (Tennyson, his masters by Grant Smith)

This was written way after Tennyson died, but **has** is used. Why? Is it grammatical?
I would use **looked to** ... but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't provide enough context. With past simple,

> Tennyson looked to Shakespeare for inspiration.

is a generalisation. Context may or may not restrict the scope, eg

> When he decided to paint his garden shed, Tennyson looked to
>   Shakespeare for inspiration.

With the present perfect, there is a built-in indication of scope:

> Tennyson has looked to Shakespeare for inspiration. But there are many other influences one can see in his works.
>
> Look at this piece. Does it ring any bells? Yes! Tennyson has looked
>   to Shakespeare for inspiration.

Comment: Tennyson is a dead poet, he is a  poet gone, he has gone to meet his maker. Of course, one can use "has looked to" but then is about the author of the piece commenting on him and not about what he did. There's an "I say" implicit in their somewhere. Oeuf corse, I am upvoting t his.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation can be found on the first line of [the Wikipedia page on present perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect):

> The present perfect is a grammatical combination of the present tense and the perfect aspect, used to express a past event that has present consequences.

It applies fairly well to your example.

Comment: Sure it does: he stared looking [to S. ...] and then stopped. That's what perfect tenses are

Comment: @user08742 - isn't the inspiration that Shakespeare still gives a fact  with present consequences ?